# How to copy selected strings translations from one android project to another?

Tags: android, string, android-studio, translation, android-resources

I have one project with lots of strings and translations. Basically, a lot of values-XX folders in res folder.

I want to copy all translations for specific strings into another project. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: other than copy and paste? there is no ... but you can: 1. move common strings to other file and copy only those files (fx `strings.xml` all other strings `common.xml` common strings ...) still copy and pasting without some scripts would be a pain in the a** or 2. make a library with string resources only and put common strings there (and reuse this library in different projects) ... 3. made some progam for that => lots of work (parsing xml config files with which string to copy, etc)

Comment: yes, I'd like to avoid copy-pasting because I have lots of strings resources.

Comment: then go for option 2

Comment: thank you for advice, but it is not an answer to my question. I need to copy string translations from one android project to another, not use shared library.

Comment: hey @AnastasiiaChervinska Have you found a solution to above question